# Using Python/Selenium to select checkboxes from an angular website

Tags: python, angularjs, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

[Here's the angular source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrQpc.jpg)

Trying to create a simple script that checks/unchecks some boxes with python/selenium.

I've thrown what little book I have at it and can't get it to correctly identify the elements. I've tried (likely incorrectly) css, xpath, label, text.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Code trial:

```
driver.find_elements_by_class_name('list-group-items')[1].click()
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
<fieldset>
  <legend>
    Step 2: Choose Data fields
  </legend>
  <div class="col-sm-5 col-lg-4">

    <div class="panel minimal minimal-gray">

      <div class="panel-title">
        <h4>
          Standard Fields:
        </h4>
      </div>

      <ul class="list-group scrollable ng-scope" id="standard-fields" ng-class="{error: ctrl.export.errors.columns}">
        <!-- ngRepeat: item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code --><li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code" class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success" ng-class="{'list-group-item-success' : item.checked}">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;Date
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code --><li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code" class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success" ng-class="{'list-group-item-success' : item.checked}">
          <input type="checkbox" ng-model="item.checked" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid">
          &nbsp;&nbsp;Time
        </li><!-- end ngRepeat: item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code --><li ng-repeat="item in ctrl.exportFormats.columns track by item.code" class="list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success" ng-class="{'list-group-item-success' : item.checked}">
```

Comment: Please include the HTML source directly in the question, as well as your Python code. This will help us answer your question.

Comment: Sure. Just updated it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. As per your code trials instead of `find_elements_by_class_name('list-group-items')[1]`, using `find_element_by_class_name('list-group-item')` would have taken you more closer.

However, as the desired elements are [Angular](https://angular.io/) elements so to click the *checkboxes* associated with the texts e.g.  **Date**, **Time** etc, you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the *element to be clickable* and you can use either of the following solutions:

- *Date*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success' and contains(@ng-repeat,'exportFormats')][contains(.,'Date')]/input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']"))).click()
  ```
- *Time*:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success' and contains(@ng-repeat,'exportFormats')][contains(.,'Time')]/input[@class='ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

Comment: You're a saint. That worked like a charm and I definitely didn't read any literature that suggested WebDriverWait as the solution.Thanks so much.

Comment: Follow up: @DebanjanB

Date worked just fine. Time hangs for about 10 seconds and then errors out.

  `line 80, in until
    raise TimeoutException(message, screen, stacktrace)
    selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:`

I tried changing 

 `list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success`

to
    `list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope`
as that was the only difference I saw but that gave me the same error.

Comment: I have cross checked the HTML you have provided. Seems both the `<li>` is having the following classes `list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success`. From that point of view our solution must have worked. I am pretty sure once you invoke `click()` on **Date** the HTML DOM gets changed.  so the _XPath_ should also be different. Can you cross check the HTML at this point (`Date` clicked but `Time` not clicked)? Is the HTML for _Time_ `<input>` same or different?

Comment: Thanks @Debanjamb. That was the issue. 

`"//li[@class='list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope list-group-item-success' and


`"//li[@class='list-group-item ng-binding ng-scope' and contains`

I thought I had checked that and after checking it again it worked. Appreciate your help.